# Django: Processing form data in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have this form for users to enter their zip code and the radius they would like to search:

```
class DistanceFilter(forms.ModelForm):

    distance = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['zipcode']
```

here is the template(filter.html):

```
{% extends 'ItsAllSport/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{{ block.super }} {# includes previous content in block #}<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 4%;">
      <form action="" method="get">
          {{ filter.form.as_p }}
          {{ distance }}
          <p>Date: <input type="text" id="id_myDate"></p>
          <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 4%;">
            <div class="content">
                {% for obj in filter.qs %}
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <!-- <div class="panel-image">
                          <img src={{ groupbuy.main_img }} class="panel-image-preview"/>
                      </div> -->
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <h4>{{ obj.title }}</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-footer text-center clearfix">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-alert" id="more_gb_info" role="button">More Info</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
          <div id="scroll-container" class="row">
              <div id="card_target"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py:

```
def event_list(request):
    advanced = EventFilter(request.GET, queryset=Event.objects.all())
    distance = DistanceFilter(request.POST or None)
    results = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DistanceFilter(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            distance = form.cleaned_data['distance']
            zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']

            for obj in Event.objects.all():
                number = check_distance(zipcode, obj.latitude, obj.longitude)
                if number <= distance:
                    results.append(obj.title)
    new = Event.objects.filter(title__in=results)

    context = {
        'filter': advanced,
        'distance': distance,
        'new': new,
        'categories':EventType.objects.all(),
        'event': Event.objects.all(),
        'login_form': LoginForm(),
        'signup_form': SignupForm(),
        }
    return render(request, 'ItsAllSport/filter.html', context)
```

Here is the check_distance function that is used on line 8:

```
import requests
from geopy.distance import vincenty

#takes in the zip code and finds the latitude and longitude
def find_coordinates(zipcode):
    url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erichurst/7882666/raw/5bdc46db47d9515269ab12ed6fb2850377fd869e/US%2520Zip%2520Codes%2520from%25202013%2520Government%2520Data"
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line[0:5] == str(zipcode):
            coords = {
                'lat': line[6:15],
                'lon': line[17:]
            }
            break

    return coords

#takes in the zip code the user entered and compares it to each Event in the database
def check_distance(user_zipcode, event_lat, event_long):
    coords = find_coordinates(user_zipcode)
    user_lat = coords['lat']
    user_long = coords['lon']

    user = (user_lat, user_long)
    event = (event_lat, event_long)

    return vincenty(user, event).miles
```

I think that the issue is in the views.py file. I have tested check_distance() and it works fine, but when I try to use the filter on the website it reloads the page and nothing happens. I do not get any errors so I assume that is not using the form data at all.

Comment: What does `event_list` return exactly? Please post the entire view. Also I recommend you use the [`django.db.gis`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries) extension to do the filtering on the database level.

Comment: I just put the entire view in the post. event_list basically just filters the database objects. I have other fields that I used django-filter for and that works fine. This is what it looks like: https://gyazo.com/a63d4b901f5910eac90ddb5868a971e2

Comment: Are you sure if form is valid? The reason you are not seeing any error is because you don't use the processed form in the template. You should pass `'login_form': form,` in the template if the request method is POST.

Comment: The login form works fine. What I am trying to do is have the objects that are within the range chosen appear below the ones that are already there(for testing purposes). That is what the "new" context is for; it uses the query that appears right above the context dictionary, and I have it in the template as well. Didn't give a full screenshot before: https://gyazo.com/b018912fe56047fb67896cd73302d3cb

Comment: please provide your template too

Comment: added the template

Comment: It seems the result is in the "new" variable, but I don't see you use it anywhere in your template.

Comment: sorry, just noticed I posted the wrong version of the template. I copied that div and replaced it with the "new" variable so I know that is not the issue. It has something to do with the event_list view function